# Position of intensive pronoun in a sentence

Tags: reflexive-pronouns

1) Man himself is responsible for his problems.

2) Man is himself responsible for his problems.

3) Man is responsible himself for his problems.

4) Man is responsible for his problems himself.

If all four are correct, then please explain the difference in meaning among them, if there is any. Also, which is preferable?

Comment: These are intensive pronouns, i.e., those that stand in apposition to a noun, here *Man*. Reflexive pronouns appear as objects as in "Man hurts **himself**." The placement of your pronouns is strictly a matter of style.

Comment: Thanks very much. I didn't know these were called intensive pronouns, and not reflexive pronouns.

Comment: @user105719 It's better to say that in the OP's examples "himself" is a reflexive pronoun used for emphasis. But they are not appositives: in 2)-4) they are part of clause structure, not NP structure, and in 1) "himself" can't stand in for the whole NP, so it doesn't qualify as an appositive (we can't say "himself is responsible ...").

Comment: @BillJ Thanks for the comment. Could you please elaborate on that a little more? What do OP and NP stand for?

Comment: OP = original poster (in this case you). NP = noun phrase.

Comment: So, examples 2, 3, 4 are correct and 1 is incorrect?

Comment: No, they are all correct.